# Galaxy S2 launcher repeatedly crashes and reboots phone following software update 20/12/2011

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, data-recovery, ota-update, boot-loop

I updated the phones software using its own software update menu option.  As part of the update process, the phone rebooted automatically.  After that, the phone just keeps rebooting itself.  As soon as the media scanner finishes scanning, the phone reboots.  the cycle is about 20-30 seconds.  During these repeated reboots I saw once an error message saying the launcher has crashed.  Since the phone keeps rebooting, I can't open a menu or do anything with it.  It does not connect to the PC as the reboot cycle is way too short.

How can I recover from this mess?  Anyone can help me?  Thank you so much.

Is there any way to backup the data from the phone?  Is there a 'safe-mode'?

My galaxy s2 uses official software, and was updated to latest software a month ago.  I checked and found there is a new update for me, so I started the process but it turned out to be a disaster.

Comment: You can try removing the SD card and see if the problem lies there. Just as an option.

Comment: Can you take it into a local store for your carrier? If you haven't done any rooting/flashing, they should fix it.